# why socket hang up error comes while trying to retrieve source from org?

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

While im trying to retrieve source from org, Im getting error as....
"Error authenticating with the refresh token due to: socket hang up"

can anyone helpme out of this?

Thanks in advnace.

Comment: I believe you're deploying to Azure App Service via Visual Studio code? Could you please confirm/share more details on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies you’re facing this issue!

Looks like you're facing the issue [reported here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/2844#issuecomment-1089619666), and you may try downgrading to VS ver.1.65 and then check if it helps.

As mentioned in the link above, until a fix is released in VS Code stable (hopefully the next major release), here are some options:

1. Downgrade to the VS Code February 2022 release.
2. Deploy via Azure CLI

Once again, we understand the inconvenience with this issue. Thanks for your patience!